# How to parse JSDoc

Tags: java, javascript, parsing, polymer, jsdoc

I have an [HTML file](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-slider/blob/master/paper-slider.html). There are some JSDoc inside like this:

```
/**
 * If true, this slider is disabled.  A disabled slider cannot be tapped
 * or dragged to change the slider value.
 *
 * @attribute disabled
 * @type boolean
 * @default false
 */
```

I need to get info and put into a bean

```
class MyBean {
    public String comment;
    public String attribute;
    public String type;
    public String defaultValue;
}
```

How do I parse my HTML file?

Comment: I'm choosing between line by line parsing with regular expressions and combined approach with some html parser and jsdoc-parse. I'm going to use nodejs tools.

Comment: Reworded for clarity.

Comment: You could also use the [Haruki](http://usejsdoc.org/about-commandline.html) template to output JSON and parse that rather than HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several JSDoc parsers out there. Take a look into [doctrine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/doctrine) and [jsdoc-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdoc-parse) for example.

Comment: Yes, jsdoc-parse parses JS code and produces JSON. It's totally fine by me. But it cannot work with .html file. I have to extract content of the <script> tag and pass it to jsdoc-parse. Unfortunatelly, I cannot just run command "jsdoc-parse paper-slider.html"

Comment: Why can't you extract the content from the `<script>` tag and run against it?

Comment: You could use a package like [gulp-html-extract](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/gulp-html-extract#example) to extract that.

Comment: Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: gulp.src("paper-slider.html").pipe(extract({ sel: "script, code.javascript" }));

Comment: Could you add jsdoc-parse to your example, please?

Comment: This is just a matter of grouping both operations into one gulp stream. I can't do your work for you.

Comment: @TarasHupalo jsdoc-parse can parse html, that is clearly documented on the readme