# How to capture certain group of text with sed?

Tags: bash, sed, jsdoc

Here's the deal, I am trying to capture all the functions with `jsdoc` below (within the `return` function), but I have been failing to do so.

So far, I tried

```
cat test.js | sed -n 's/.*\(\/\*\).*/\1/p'
```

but all I got was
`/*`

I would like to retrieve this:

```
   /**
    * Gets the Confirm button
    *
    * @returns {button>}
    */
    function getConfirmButton() {
        return find(button);
    }
```

Here is the file from which I am trying to extract text.

```
import sth;
const stuff = () => {

    return {
        /**
        * Gets the Confirm button
        *
        * @returns {button>}
        */
        function getConfirmButton() {
            return find(button);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logic is unclear (at least to me). You want to print everything from the first "/*" to... the next pair of closing braces separated by nothing but whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- there is a reason OP is not using a `jsdoc`-aware tool to parse the data (eg, [How to parse JSDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28972262))
- while the sample only shows one (sub) function defined within the `return` function ...
- from OPs comment - "*capture all the functions ... (within the **return** function)*" - I take this to mean there could be more than 1 function to be returned
- OP is ok with returning everything that exists within the `return {` and `}` boundaries (eg, functions, comments, blank lines)
- the source is syntactically correct (eg, all left braces (`{`) have a matching right brace (`}`)
- outside the chunk of code we wish to display, the word `return` only shows up in the name of the one function we're interested in

Sample input (with some 'extra' functions and comments to demonstrate the solution):

```
$ cat test.js
import sth;
const stuff = () => {

    return {
        /**                                                  # first line of output
        * Gets the Confirm button
        *
        * @returns {button>}
        */
        function getConfirmButton() {
            return find(button);
        }
    another_function () { some stuff }

      and_one_more_function() {
       with some lines
in here that are total
   rubbish }
     /** some extra comments
      **/                                                    # last line of output
    }                                                        # matches with "return {"
}
```

One `awk` solution based on counting left and right braces (`{ => +1` / `} => -1`):

```
awk '
/return.*{/ { count=1 ; next }                               # start of the parent function "return"; left brace sets count = 1
! count     { next }                                         # if count == 0 => not interested in this line of input
            { split($0,arr,"[{}]",delims)                    # split line by delimiters "{" and "}", saving actual delimiters in the delims[] array
              for ( i in delims )                            # loop through list of delimiters
                  ( delims[i] == "{" ) ? count++ : count--   # increment count for each "{" and decrement count for each "}"
              if (count) print                               # if count > 0 then print the current line
            }
' test.js
```

This generates:

```
        /**
        * Gets the Confirm button
        *
        */
        function getConfirmButton() {
            return find(button);
        }
    another_function () { some stuff }

      and_one_more_function() {
       with some lines
in here that are total
   rubbish }
     /** some extra comments
      **/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -rzn s'/(^.*)(\/\*\*.*find\(button\)\;[[:space:]]+})(.*$)/\2/p' test.js
```

Consume the file as one line with -z. Split the file into 3 sections using regular expressions (-r). Substitute the line for the second section and print.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the white space before the terminating `}` matching the white space before the starting `return` with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`:

```
$ awk '
     f { if (index($0,end)==1) f=0; else print; next }
     match($0,/^(\s*)return/,a) { f=1; end=a[1]"}" }
' file
        /**
        * Gets the Confirm button
        *
        * @returns {button>}
        */
        function getConfirmButton() {
            return find(button);
        }
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk '
    f { if (index($0,end)==1) f=0; else print; next }
    match($0,/^[[:space:]]*return/) { f=1; end=substr($0,1,RLENGTH-6)"}" }
' file
        /**
        * Gets the Confirm button
        *
        * @returns {button>}
        */
        function getConfirmButton() {
            return find(button);
        }
```